# Android - Alarm Manager to run a service at 5am each morning

Tags: android, date, time, alarmmanager

I need to run my update service at 5am each morning so the data is refreshed when the user picks up their phone in the moring. The code I have so far is -

```
Log.d(TAG, "setAutoRun");
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RefreshIntentService.class);
PendingIntent pendingI = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60); // this was just to test out the alarm service
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingI);
```

How can I modify this do that it'll run each morning at 5am?
I know I can set an interval so it will run again in X minutes, but how can I start it at 5am if the user won't open it then.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe editing your `Calendar params` like this should work and change to `setRepeating()`

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);   

alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingI);
```

[AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_DAY)

Comment: also, btw, the `setRepeating` method need 4 args so it looks like this- `alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time.getTimeInMillis(),86400000 , pendingI);`  86400000  is 24 hours in miliseconds

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I was rushing. I have edited my answer, thanks. `AlarmManager` has constants for that as I put in my edit.

Comment: I used code above but still doesn't work. The alarm manager didn't execute my task on midnight. `time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);`

Comment: @codeMagic, I have used                                                                 Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);  for starting the alarm at 9 am. but as soon as I am starting my main activity, the alarm is getting set.but it should start at 9 am only.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setRepeating method, in which one you can pass the especific time. Look this example:

```
private void scheduleAlarms() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AlarmActivity.class);
        mPendMorInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mContext, Constants.ALARM_MORNING_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        mPendAftInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mContext, Constants.ALARM_AFTERNOON_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        List<Long> alarms = SelectorAlarm.timeAlarms(mContext);
        if (alarms.size() >= 1) {
            mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getRightTimeAlarm(alarms.get(Constants.MORNING)),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mPendMorInt);
            mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getRightTimeAlarm(alarms.get(Constants.AFTERNOON)),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mPendAftInt);
        }
    }
```